# How to write data to firebase like this format in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

How to write data to firebase like this format?

[image]

the `qHFij7jKyTa1t9RhkWN2LImqwVl2` is User ID,  the `-MjYl_8EVJJkWcHgn6mJ` is post ID,

I tried to used this code

```
await _firestore
            .collection('Notifications')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection(postid)
            .doc()
            .set({
          'userid': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
          'comment': 'test',
          'postid': postid,
          'ispost': true,
          'time': DateTime.now(),
        });
```

[image]

But it was not I want it.

In my old project in Android, the code is

```
ref = ref.getInstance.getReference("Notifications").child(publisherid);
HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
hashmap.put("userid", userid);
hashmap.put("comment", comment);
hashmap.put("postid", postid);
hashmap.put("ispost", true);
hashmap.put("time", DateTime.now());
```

How can do like this format?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create sub-collection by following way.

```
CollectionReference notifications = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Notifications');

notifications.doc('qHFij7jKyTa1t9RhkWN2LImqwVl2').collection('MjYl_8EVJJkWcHgn6mJ').add({
            'comment': 'liked your post',
            'isPost': 'true', 
          });
```

Comment: can't do it, it's same to my code problem

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Notifications')

.doc('qHFij7jKyTa1t9RhkWN2LImqwVl2').collection('MjYl_8EVJJkWcHgn6mJ')

.add({
'comment': 'liked your post',
'isPost': 'true',
});

Comment: can't do it, it's same to my code problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).